# Could not find tag for codec none in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container vs Non-monotonous DTS in output stream

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, streaming, codec

I'm trying to record video from my ip camera stream with ffmpeg in command line.

```
fmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp \
>  -i rtsp://192.168.0.250/stream1 \
>  -c copy \
>  -map 0 \
>  -f segment \
>  -segment_time 60 \
>  -segment_format mp4 \
>  "/home/video/stream-%010d.mp4"
```

and got the next output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://192.168.0.250/stream1':
  Metadata:
    title           : Session streamed by "nessyMediaServer"
    comment         : h264
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 2048x1536 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Data: none
[segment @ 0x559e20000980] Opening '/home/video/stream-0000000000.mp4' for writing
[mp4 @ 0x559e1fffc180] Could not find tag for codec none in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

Tried some different options like -c:v libx265 or -c:v libx264 but it does not works the output is a little different. But the main error is the same:

```
Could not find tag for codec none in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

Then I've tried to change output format:

```
 ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp \
 -i rtsp://192.168.0.250/stream1 \
 -c copy \
 -map 0 \
 -f segment \
 -segment_time 60 \
 -segment_format avi \
 "/home/video/stream-%010d.avi"
```

It started to record video (records 2 corrupt video files) but with errors:

```
fmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://192.168.0.250/stream1':
  Metadata:
    title           : Session streamed by "nessyMediaServer"
    comment         : h265
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 2048x1536 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Data: none
[segment @ 0x562200721d80] Opening '/home/evgeniy/video/stream-0000000000.avi' for writing
Output #0, segment, to '/home/video/stream-%010d.avi':
  Metadata:
    title           : Session streamed by "nessyMediaServer"
    comment         : h265
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 2048x1536 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Data: none
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[segment @ 0x562200721d80] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[segment @ 0x562200721d80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 202, current: 202; changing to 203. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
...
[segment @ 0x562200721d80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 748, current: 748; changing to 749. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[segment @ 0x562200721d80] Opening '/home/video/stream-0000000001.avi' for writing
[avi @ 0x56220077d800] Too large number of skipped frames 5417887 > 6000001x    
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
[avi @ 0x56220077d800] Too large number of skipped frames 5407879 > 60000
frame= 1505 fps= 25 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:01:00.24 bitrate=N/A speed=1.01x    
video:5314kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:359kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

That I've tried: to add some different keys (one at a time) `-fflags +genpts`, `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1` , `-thread_queue_size 512` , `-vsync 0 -enc_time_base -1`  nothing of these works. Also tried `-reset_timestamps 1`  this outputs video files but they all are corrupt.
What else I can try to save video from rtsp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stream #0:1 is unknown data, but the MP4 muxer does not know what to do with that.

- Map only the video by changing `-map 0` to `-map 0:v`.
- Or keep `-map 0` and omit the data stream by adding `-map -0:d`.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).

Comment: Yes. it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: When I tried to run commands with your fixes the first file is correctly wrote but the next videos have incorrect meta data. For example second video contains the wrong metadata for the start time of video 1 minute and time of the end of the video is also 1 minute. And for the over videos is the same issue for third video start time is 2 minute and end time 1 minute and so on. It is also not possible to scroll the slider to watch a specific part of the video. Is there some way to fix that?

Comment: @Kracozebr This is a completely different issue. Try adding `-reset_timestamps 1`. See [segment muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment) for more info.